# Named SQL queries

Tags: hibernate

I have created domain objects using annotations and now I need some sql queries to be written to fetch/insert/update data from/to more than one table.

Is there a way to keep only the sql queries in the hbm.xml file as named query because the domain objects are already created using annotations and I do not need to do it in xml way. If this is possible then what are the steps need to be followed, please advice.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the bellow tag in your xml file

```
<sql-query name="Myquery">
   select * from YourTableName
</sql-query>
```

Check this example
http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/example-on-hibernate-named-queries/

Comment: My aim is to use annotated domain object with a named query xml, how to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Solved. You need to put all the columns of the table in the select clause even if you need few because it populates the complete domain object.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly define a sql-query in hbm.xml like:

```
<sql-query name="persons"> 
  <return alias="person"  class="eg.Person"/> 
 Select person.NAME AS {person.name},person.AGE AS {person.age},person.SEX AS {person.sex} FROM PERSON person Where person.NAME LIKE :namePattern
</sql-query>
```

and then fetch it by the statment's name:

```
List people = sess.getNamedQuery("persons").setString("namePattern" ,namePattern)
.setMaxResults( 50 )
.list();
```

Another way, the sql-query element is unneeded, write java code directly:

List cats = sess.createSQLQuery(

```
"select {cat.*}, {kitten.*} from cats cat, cats kitten where kitten.mother = cat.id ")
.addEntity("cat" , Cat. class)         // add entity
.addJoin("kitten" ,  "cat.kittens ")   // add related entity 
.list();
```

Maybe help you:)

Comment: I have to use named query in a xml file and here is the query: SELECT appl.applicant_id as applicantId,
 appl.airport_id as airportId,
 appl.first_name as firstName,
 appl.ssn as ssn
FROM applicant appl, enroll_request enroll
WHERE enroll.applicant_id = appl.applicant_id
 and enroll.application_id = :applicationId.    How my xml file should look like?

Comment: this is my entry in the xml which throws error: 
<hibernate-mapping>
 <import class="com.dtis.dac.domain.Applicant"/>
 <import class="com.dtis.dac.domain.EnrollmentRequest"/>
 
 <query name="getUniqueApplicant">
        <![CDATA[
   SELECT appl.applicant_id as applicantId,
         appl.airport_id as airportId,
       appl.first_name as firstName,
       appl.ssn as ssn
   FROM   applicant appl, enroll_request enroll
   WHERE  enroll.applicant_id = appl.applicant_id
      and enroll.application_id = :applicationId
  ]]>
 </query>
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: I have this query printed on consode:  Hibernate: 
    SELECT
        appl.applicant_id as applicantId,
        appl.airport_id as airportId,
        appl.first_name as firstName,
        appl.ssn as ssn    
    FROM
        applicant appl,
        enroll_request enroll    
    WHERE
        enroll.applicant_id = appl.applicant_id       
        and enroll.application_id = ?                              this works when I test it using a database editor like SQL server mngmnt studio but fails saying: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Invalid column name applicant_id.  PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: I want a named query for the two Hibernate domain objects, Applicant and EnrollRequest. Right now I have some Applicant column selected but I actually want the Applicant object to be returned. 

The query is:    SELECT appl.applicant_id as {applicant.applicantId},
         appl.airport_id as {applicant.airportId},
       appl.first_name as {applicant.firstName},
       appl.ssn as {applicant.ssn}
   FROM   applicant appl, enroll_request enroll
   WHERE  enroll.applicant_id = appl.applicant_id
      and enroll.application_id = :applicationId

How my xml file should look like? Please help.